# Taxonomy term RestApi data 10 rows limitions

Tags: categories, taxonomy, terms, rest-api

i have created a pod taxonomy(Products) in Wordpress ... 
i have 16 item of terms(categories) for product taxonomy ...
but after going to this routes : 
http://...../wp-json/wp/v2/product_categories , 
in RestApi , it gives me just 10 row(arrays) of object ...

i want to have more that 10 rows(ids) of Api Data in term of taxonomies in Wordpress ...

how can i can get full arrays of terms in restApi ? is it somthing with php coding in theme php files or no just in pod admin plugin settings?

Answer (score 0):

Querying custom taxonomy terms is the same as querying categories, and as you can see from [the docs](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/reference/categories/) you can change the number returned using the `per_page` argument:

```
http://...../wp-json/wp/v2/product_categories?per_page=100
```

Comment: thakn you so muchhh brooooo

Comment: If the answer help, please mark the answer as accepted so others can see that your question has an answer.